# Not able to store values from dynamic drop list into database on mysql(php)

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

this is starva i need your help for storing values into database here is my code i want to store the values fetched from list into database '$post[]'

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>order</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
  <form action="order2.php" method="post">
  <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="show"></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="order" value="Order"></td>
   </tr>    
   </table>

    <!________________________________!>
    <?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="mess_db";
    $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    if(!$con)
    {
        Die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
    }
    if($con)
    {
     echo "DB Connected<br>";
    }
    mysql_select_db($database,$con);
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  menu";
        $result= mysql_query($sql,$con);
        echo '<select name="roti">';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo '<option value="'. $row['roti'].'">' . $row['roti'].'';

        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

    }
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  menu";

        $result= mysql_query($sql,$con);

        echo '<select name="sabji">';


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['sabji'].'">' . $row['sabji'].'';

        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

    }
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  menu";

        $result= mysql_query($sql,$con);

        echo '<select name="daal">';


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['daal'].'">' . $row['daal'].'';

        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

    }

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  menu";

        $result= mysql_query($sql,$con);

        echo '<select name="sweet">';


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['sweet'].'">' . $row['sweet'].'';

        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

    }

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  menu";

        $result= mysql_query($sql,$con);

        echo '<select name="starter">';


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        echo '<option value=" ' . $row['starter'].'">' . $row['starter'].'';

        }
        echo '</select><br><br>';

    }
    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
    echo "Hi...";
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="mess_db";

    $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);

    if(!$con){
    Die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
             }

    if($con){
     echo "DB Connected<br>";
           }

    mysql_select_db($database,$con);
    if(!$_POST=="")
    {

    $sql="INSERT INTO order VALUES('$_POST[roti]')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
    echo "Hello";
    }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

please help me on this topic
i ma not at all getting any error and database is still empty

Comment: Can you provide your DB Structure? you need to implode $_POST[roti] before passing into query

Comment: you want to retrieve files from db and display the result on a dropdown input?

Comment: i am fetching the list from table when i click on show button, now i want to store the values of that list into another table which is "order" table it has many fields like order id orderdate and other things and its also getting the selected values into variable but its just not storing in into database

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' i already fetched from database into dropdown list i want to store those option selected from list into different table in database

Comment: @sandeepsure here is my database structure m fetching data from menu table which contains menuid,roti,sabji,daal,starter,sweet and want to store it into Order table which has these fields already in it